# Bibtex not putting a space between the author name and "and"

Tags: bibliographies, revtex

I am working on bibliography with Bibtex, but have encountered a problem.

When there are two authors, Bibtex will not put a space between the author's name and the "and".
If you check the attached image, you can easily see the problem.

How do you solve this problem?
I am using RevTex 4.2 on Overleaf.com, compiled with "Latex compiler" and Tex live version 2020.

Update

- It seems that the bibtex style file is *apsrev4-2.bst* because the "prx" option is selected.
- I have copied the bibtex source from Google scholar and here is what is shown in the image:

```
@article{abreu2011extracting,
  title={Extracting work from a single heat bath through feedback},
  author={Abreu, David and Seifert, Udo},
  journal={EPL (Europhysics Letters)},
  volume={94},
  number={1},
  pages={10001},
  year={2011},
  publisher={IOP Publishing}
}

@article{munakata2012entropy,
  title={Entropy production and fluctuation theorems under feedback control: the molecular refrigerator model revisited},
  author={Munakata, T and Rosinberg, ML},
  journal={Journal of Statistical Mechanics: Theory and Experiment},
  volume={2012},
  number={05},
  pages={P05010},
  year={2012},
  publisher={IOP Publishing}
}
```

[image]

Comment: Please tell us which bibliography style you employ, and please edit your posting to show the bibtex source code for the two entries in question.

Comment: @Mico I updated the question to add what you mentioned. Thank you!

Comment: Are you sure your document employs the `apsrev4-2` bib style? The reason I ask is that I am unable to reproduce the screenshot you posted when I create a minimal compilable test file and then compile it either with Overleaf or with my local TeX distribution. If the bib file is called `mybib.bib`, then the output of the test file `\documentclass{article} \usepackage[numbers]{natbib} \bibliographystyle{apsrev4-2} \begin{document} \nocite{*} \bibliography{mybib} \end{document}` generates a pdf file whose bib entries is very different. Please provide more information about what you're doing.

Comment: @Mico Thank you for your kind support. After reading your comment, I thought I might have broken something in RevTex, so I created a new one from the Overleaf template and moved all my files over, which solved the problem. I have not been able to identify what the problem was. Thanks for your support, I solved the problem. Thank you again.